Почему SVG обрезается после объединения path?
У меня есть SVG, указанный ниже. Я объединил все пути в один.
Но мой окончательный SVG обрезается. Может кто-нибудь помочь?
Скриншоты до и после прилагаются:
Было:


<svg width="21" height="22" viewBox="0 0 21 22" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M18.5952 17.7136L16.8883 14.2878C16.7414 14.0032 16.4482 13.8138 16.1284 13.8138H12.968V10.7403C12.968 10.2664 12.5815 9.8739 12.1149 9.8739C11.6482 9.8739 11.2617 10.2664 11.2617 10.7403V14.6808C11.2617 15.1548 11.6482 15.5472 12.1149 15.5472H15.6081L17.0748 18.4992C17.2217 18.797 17.5279 18.9731 17.8347 18.9731C17.968 18.9731 18.1014 18.9461 18.2211 18.8784C18.6347 18.6615 18.8082 18.1468 18.5952 17.7136Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M14.3166 17.0235C13.7301 17.5381 12.9832 17.8359 12.2098 17.8359C10.4499 17.8359 9.03624 16.3872 9.03624 14.6132C9.03624 13.6114 9.48937 12.6767 10.2764 12.0543C10.6498 11.7565 10.7165 11.2149 10.4232 10.8356C10.13 10.4564 9.59668 10.3887 9.22323 10.6865C8.00967 11.6343 7.31641 13.056 7.31641 14.5994C7.31641 17.3344 9.50284 19.5555 12.1967 19.5555C13.3832 19.5555 14.5165 19.1223 15.4233 18.3231C15.7832 18.0115 15.8098 17.4699 15.5035 17.1044C15.2098 16.7527 14.6635 16.7252 14.3166 17.0235Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M13.5587 7.91063C13.5587 8.7257 12.9077 9.38628 12.1053 9.38628C11.3027 9.38628 10.6523 8.72565 10.6523 7.91063C10.6523 7.09562 11.3028 6.43445 12.1053 6.43445C12.9078 6.43445 13.5587 7.0956 13.5587 7.91063Z" fill="black"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M7.34438 18.4364C7.34438 18.8637 6.99197 19.2103 6.55707 19.2103C6.12237 19.2103 5.76976 18.8639 5.76976 18.4364V13.1549C5.76976 13.0758 5.70415 13.0113 5.62374 13.0113H5.60087C5.52045 13.0113 5.45484 13.0758 5.45484 13.1549V18.4364C5.45484 18.8637 5.10242 19.2103 4.66753 19.2103C4.23263 19.2103 3.88022 18.8639 3.88022 18.4364C3.88022 15.0285 3.88022 11.3636 3.88022 7.93933C3.88022 7.86028 3.81461 7.79579 3.73419 7.79579H3.71132C3.63091 7.79579 3.5653 7.86028 3.5653 7.93933C3.5653 9.40132 3.5653 10.5185 3.5653 11.9805C3.5653 12.3153 3.28918 12.5868 2.94876 12.5868C2.60815 12.5868 2.33203 12.3153 2.33203 11.9805C2.33203 10.4045 2.33203 9.17356 2.33203 7.59752C2.33203 6.64743 3.12028 5.87258 4.08679 5.87258C5.10374 5.87258 6.12087 5.87258 7.13781 5.87258C8.10432 5.87258 8.89257 6.64743 8.89257 7.59752C8.89257 9.17356 8.89257 10.4045 8.89257 11.9805C8.89257 12.3153 8.61645 12.5868 8.27584 12.5868C7.93524 12.5868 7.65931 12.3153 7.65931 11.9805C7.65931 10.5185 7.65931 9.40132 7.65931 7.93933C7.65931 7.86028 7.5937 7.79579 7.51328 7.79579H7.49041C7.40999 7.79579 7.34438 7.86028 7.34438 7.93933C7.34438 11.3638 7.34438 15.0287 7.34438 18.4364ZM5.6123 2.44446C6.44704 2.44446 7.12394 3.10967 7.12394 3.9304C7.12394 4.75094 6.44722 5.41634 5.6123 5.41634C4.77738 5.41634 4.10067 4.75113 4.10067 3.9304C4.10067 3.10967 4.77757 2.44446 5.6123 2.44446Z" fill="black"/>
</svg>



Стало:


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   version="1.1"
   x="0px" y="0px"
   width="24px"
   height="24px"
   viewBox="0 0 24 24"
   id="companion-24">
   
<!-- Объединены все paths -->
<path fill="#000000" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M18.5952 17.7136L16.8883 14.2878C16.7414 14.0032 16.4482 13.8138 16.1284 13.8138H12.968V10.7403C12.968 10.2664 12.5815 9.8739 12.1149 9.8739C11.6482 9.8739 11.2617 10.2664 11.2617 10.7403V14.6808C11.2617 15.1548 11.6482 15.5472 12.1149 15.5472H15.6081L17.0748 18.4992C17.2217 18.797 17.5279 18.9731 17.8347 18.9731C17.968 18.9731 18.1014 18.9461 18.2211 18.8784C18.6347 18.6615 18.8082 18.1468 18.5952 17.7136ZM14.3166 17.0235C13.7301 17.5381 12.9832 17.8359 12.2098 17.8359C10.4499 17.8359 9.03624 16.3872 9.03624 14.6132C9.03624 13.6114 9.48937 12.6767 10.2764 12.0543C10.6498 11.7565 10.7165 11.2149 10.4232 10.8356C10.13 10.4564 9.59668 10.3887 9.22323 10.6865C8.00967 11.6343 7.31641 13.056 7.31641 14.5994C7.31641 17.3344 9.50284 19.5555 12.1967 19.5555C13.3832 19.5555 14.5165 19.1223 15.4233 18.3231C15.7832 18.0115 15.8098 17.4699 15.5035 17.1044C15.2098 16.7527 14.6635 16.7252 14.3166 17.0235ZM13.5587 7.91063C13.5587 8.7257 12.9077 9.38628 12.1053 9.38628C11.3027 9.38628 10.6523 8.72565 10.6523 7.91063C10.6523 7.09562 11.3028 6.43445 12.1053 6.43445C12.9078 6.43445 13.5587 7.0956 13.5587 7.91063ZM7.34438 18.4364C7.34438 18.8637 6.99197 19.2103 6.55707 19.2103C6.12237 19.2103 5.76976 18.8639 5.76976 18.4364V13.1549C5.76976 13.0758 5.70415 13.0113 5.62374 13.0113H5.60087C5.52045 13.0113 5.45484 13.0758 5.45484 13.1549V18.4364C5.45484 18.8637 5.10242 19.2103 4.66753 19.2103C4.23263 19.2103 3.88022 18.8639 3.88022 18.4364C3.88022 15.0285 3.88022 11.3636 3.88022 7.93933C3.88022 7.86028 3.81461 7.79579 3.73419 7.79579H3.71132C3.63091 7.79579 3.5653 7.86028 3.5653 7.93933C3.5653 9.40132 3.5653 10.5185 3.5653 11.9805C3.5653 12.3153 3.28918 12.5868 2.94876 12.5868C2.60815 12.5868 2.33203 12.3153 2.33203 11.9805C2.33203 10.4045 2.33203 9.17356 2.33203 7.59752C2.33203 6.64743 3.12028 5.87258 4.08679 5.87258C5.10374 5.87258 6.12087 5.87258 7.13781 5.87258C8.10432 5.87258 8.89257 6.64743 8.89257 7.59752C8.89257 9.17356 8.89257 10.4045 8.89257 11.9805C8.89257 12.3153 8.61645 12.5868 8.27584 12.5868C7.93524 12.5868 7.65931 12.3153 7.65931 11.9805C7.65931 10.5185 7.65931 9.40132 7.65931 7.93933C7.65931 7.86028 7.5937 7.79579 7.51328 7.79579H7.49041C7.40999 7.79579 7.34438 7.86028 7.34438 7.93933C7.34438 11.3638 7.34438 15.0287 7.34438 18.4364ZM5.6123 2.44446C6.44704 2.44446 7.12394 3.10967 7.12394 3.9304C7.12394 4.75094 6.44722 5.41634 5.6123 5.41634C4.77738 5.41634 4.10067 4.75113 4.10067 3.9304C4.10067 3.10967 4.77757 2.44446 5.6123 2.44446Z"/>
</svg>




Свободный перевод вопроса Why SVG is clipping after merging paths? от участника  @Dolly.

ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/79088604/7394871

Вместо сложного реверсирования векторных путей накладывающихся элементов можно в любом редакторе объединить эти пути. То есть, объединить фигуры туловища стоящего человечка и кресла в одну замкнутую фигуру.


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 55 55" id="companion-24">

  <path d="M10.24 0.83c2.61,0 4.73,2.08 4.73,4.64 0,2.57 -2.12,4.65 -4.73,4.65 -2.61,0 -4.72,-2.08 -4.72,-4.65 0,-2.56 2.11,-4.64 4.72,-4.64zm40.58 47.72l-5.34 -10.71c-0.46,-0.89 -1.37,-1.48 -2.37,-1.48l-9.88 0 0 -9.6c0,-1.49 -1.21,-2.71 -2.67,-2.71 -1.45,0 -2.66,1.22 -2.66,2.71l0 12.31c0,1.48 1.21,2.71 2.66,2.71l10.92 0 4.58 9.22c0.46,0.93 1.42,1.48 2.38,1.48 0.42,0 0.83,-0.08 1.21,-0.29 1.29,-0.68 1.83,-2.29 1.17,-3.64zm-13.38 -2.16c-1.83,1.61 -4.16,2.54 -6.58,2.54 -5.5,0 -9.92,-4.53 -9.92,-10.07 0,-3.13 1.42,-6.05 3.88,-8 1.17,-0.93 1.37,-2.62 0.46,-3.81 -0.92,-1.18 -2.59,-1.39 -3.75,-0.46 -0.36,0.28 -0.71,0.57 -1.04,0.88l0 -10.54c0,-2.97 -2.46,-5.39 -5.48,-5.39 -3.18,0 -6.36,0 -9.53,0 -3.02,0 -5.49,2.42 -5.49,5.39 0,4.93 0,8.78 0,13.7 0,1.05 0.87,1.9 1.93,1.9 1.06,0 1.93,-0.85 1.93,-1.9 0,-4.57 0,-8.06 0,-12.63 0,-0.25 0.2,-0.45 0.45,-0.45l0.07 0c0.26,0 0.46,0.2 0.46,0.45 0,10.7 0,22.16 0,32.81 0,1.33 1.1,2.41 2.46,2.41 1.36,0 2.46,-1.08 2.46,-2.41l0 -16.51c0,-0.25 0.21,-0.45 0.46,-0.45l0.07 0c0.25,0 0.46,0.2 0.46,0.45l0 16.51c0,1.33 1.1,2.41 2.46,2.41 1.36,0 2.46,-1.08 2.46,-2.41l0 -10.34c0.81,7.77 7.29,13.83 15.16,13.83 3.71,0 7.25,-1.35 10.08,-3.85 1.13,-0.97 1.21,-2.66 0.25,-3.81 -0.91,-1.1 -2.62,-1.18 -3.71,-0.25zm-20.28 -14.46c-0.8,1.62 -1.31,3.38 -1.5,5.22l0 -19.15c0,-0.25 0.2,-0.45 0.45,-0.45l0.07 0c0.26,0 0.46,0.2 0.46,0.45 0,4.57 0,8.06 0,12.63 0,0.5 0.2,0.96 0.52,1.3zm17.92 -14.02c0,2.55 -2.04,4.61 -4.55,4.61 -2.5,0 -4.54,-2.06 -4.54,-4.61 0,-2.54 2.04,-4.61 4.54,-4.61 2.51,0 4.55,2.07 4.55,4.61z"/>
</svg>




Для одноцветных иконок это решение вполне реально. Для многоцветных иконок нужно несколько path, чтобы каждый раскрашивать в свой цвет.

@Alexandr_TT так он и объединил всё в один path, с этого всё и началось. Часть этого пути предлагается реверсировать, то есть надо парсить d, обнаруживать нужный участок, а затем в редакторе менять направление. Уже потом опять включить путь в нужное место "шифрованной" строки. И в итоге цвет будет один, путь один. А можно закинуть SVG в редактор, отменить группировку, выделить все пути и слить в единый. Два движения мышкой.

повторю свое мнение: при объединении нескольких path в один теряется возможность раскрашивать разные части иконки в разные цвета. Например человек одного цвета, коляска другого цвета.

А как можно раскрасить разные участки в ответе @enxaneta? Никак.

никак не раскрасить - path один. Я нигде не говорил, что  ответ enxaneta лучше твоего. Я только высказал свои соображения. Просто сейчас в тренде многоцветные иконки. Ответ перевел только из-за мощной утилиты Reverse path в его авторстве. :)

Ну и мой ответ в контексте вопроса и ответа корейского гуру svg) В самом вопросе автор объединил всё в один path и встретил проблему. И ответ решает проблему вычитания наложения путей. Глупо мне будет в переводе уговаривать автора вопроса оставить отдельные пути и раскрашивать в разный цвет, модно мол)

он не корейский гуру, а испанец и живет в каталония, преподователь словесности в частном пансионате. SVG его хобби. Утилиту reverse он создал ещё в 2016 году

Чтобы решить задачу, вам нужно будет перевернуть (поменять местами начало и конец пути) второй путь, тот, который рисует инвалидную коляску.
В противном случае перекрывающаяся часть пути будет пустой.
Пожалуйста, прочтите больше о  fill-rule in SVG и здесь


<svg width="210" height="220" viewBox="0 0 21 22" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M18.5952 17.7136L16.8883 14.2878C16.7414 14.0032 16.4482 13.8138 16.1284 13.8138H12.968V10.7403C12.968 10.2664 12.5815 9.8739 12.1149 9.8739C11.6482 9.8739 11.2617 10.2664 11.2617 10.7403V14.6808C11.2617 15.1548 11.6482 15.5472 12.1149 15.5472H15.6081L17.0748 18.4992C17.2217 18.797 17.5279 18.9731 17.8347 18.9731C17.968 18.9731 18.1014 18.9461 18.2211 18.8784C18.6347 18.6615 18.8082 18.1468 18.5952 17.7136Z
         M14.3166,17.0235L14.3166,17.0235C14.6635,16.7252 15.2098,16.7527 15.5035,17.1044C15.8098,17.4699 15.7832,18.0115 15.4233,18.3231C14.5165,19.1223 13.3832,19.5555 12.1967,19.5555C9.50284,19.5555 7.31641,17.3344 7.31641,14.5994C7.31641,13.056 8.00967,11.6343 9.22323,10.6865C9.59668,10.3887 10.13,10.4564 10.4232,10.8356C10.7165,11.2149 10.6498,11.7565 10.2764,12.0543C9.48937,12.6767 9.03624,13.6114 9.03624,14.6132C9.03624,16.3872 10.4499,17.8359 12.2098,17.8359C12.9832,17.8359 13.7301,17.5381 14.3166,17.0235Z
         M13.5587 7.91063C13.5587 8.7257 12.9077 9.38628 12.1053 9.38628C11.3027 9.38628 10.6523 8.72565 10.6523 7.91063C10.6523 7.09562 11.3028 6.43445 12.1053 6.43445C12.9078 6.43445 13.5587 7.0956 13.5587 7.91063Z 
         M7.34438 18.4364C7.34438 18.8637 6.99197 19.2103 6.55707 19.2103C6.12237 19.2103 5.76976 18.8639 5.76976 18.4364V13.1549C5.76976 13.0758 5.70415 13.0113 5.62374 13.0113H5.60087C5.52045 13.0113 5.45484 13.0758 5.45484 13.1549V18.4364C5.45484 18.8637 5.10242 19.2103 4.66753 19.2103C4.23263 19.2103 3.88022 18.8639 3.88022 18.4364C3.88022 15.0285 3.88022 11.3636 3.88022 7.93933C3.88022 7.86028 3.81461 7.79579 3.73419 7.79579H3.71132C3.63091 7.79579 3.5653 7.86028 3.5653 7.93933C3.5653 9.40132 3.5653 10.5185 3.5653 11.9805C3.5653 12.3153 3.28918 12.5868 2.94876 12.5868C2.60815 12.5868 2.33203 12.3153 2.33203 11.9805C2.33203 10.4045 2.33203 9.17356 2.33203 7.59752C2.33203 6.64743 3.12028 5.87258 4.08679 5.87258C5.10374 5.87258 6.12087 5.87258 7.13781 5.87258C8.10432 5.87258 8.89257 6.64743 8.89257 7.59752C8.89257 9.17356 8.89257 10.4045 8.89257 11.9805C8.89257 12.3153 8.61645 12.5868 8.27584 12.5868C7.93524 12.5868 7.65931 12.3153 7.65931 11.9805C7.65931 10.5185 7.65931 9.40132 7.65931 7.93933C7.65931 7.86028 7.5937 7.79579 7.51328 7.79579H7.49041C7.40999 7.79579 7.34438 7.86028 7.34438 7.93933C7.34438 11.3638 7.34438 15.0287 7.34438 18.4364ZM5.6123 2.44446C6.44704 2.44446 7.12394 3.10967 7.12394 3.9304C7.12394 4.75094 6.44722 5.41634 5.6123 5.41634C4.77738 5.41634 4.10067 4.75113 4.10067 3.9304C4.10067 3.10967 4.77757 2.44446 5.6123 2.44446Z" />
</svg>



Свободный перевод  ответа от участника  @enxaneta.

А non-zero нельзя было применить? В ответе есть ссылка на fill-rule, а фактически путь переписан в редакторе или что?

Я понял, здесь речь о взаимном направлении двух элементов и что считается пересечением с вычитанием,  что нет. Ссылка на определение nonzero. Поэтому исправлять только реверсией векторов. Но для этого опять редактор, хотя в редакторе эти пути как раз можно было объединить в один и всё.

Reverse SVG path
Автор ответа enxaneta разработал утилиту для реверса любого path:


let the_d, closed, lc_d_ry, the_d_ry, theReversedD;

Init();

TA.addEventListener("input", () => {
  Init();
});

function Init() {
  // the value of the d is the value of the textarea
  the_d = TA.value;
  // set the d atteibute of the path
  thePath.setAttributeNS(null, "d", the_d);
  // set the viewBox of the svg element
  setViewBox(thePath);
  // is the path closed?
  closed = null;
  //formatedArgsArray takes care of long commands
  lc_d_ry = formatedArgsArray(the_d);
  //SVG2UpperCase changes all commands to uppercase
  the_d_ry = SVG2UpperCase(lc_d_ry);

  // get the reversed d
  theReversedD = getNewD(the_d_ry);
  // set the attribute d for the reversedPath
  reversedPath.setAttributeNS(null, "d", theReversedD);
  output.textContent = theReversedD;
}

function setViewBox(thePath) {
  let BB = thePath.getBBox();
  let viewBx = `${BB.x - 10} ${BB.y - 10} ${BB.width + 20} ${BB.height + 20}`;
  theSVG.setAttributeNS(null, "viewBox", viewBx);

  reversedSVG.setAttributeNS(null, "viewBox", viewBx);
}

// ---------Functions used to reverse the path
function getNewD(the_d_ry) {
  let commands = S2C_T2Q(the_d_ry);
  closed = ifClosedPath(commands);

  let newD = "M";
  let c, lastX, lastY, lastUC;

  for (let i = commands.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    c = commands[i];
    lastX = c[c.length - 2];
    lastY = c[c.length - 1];

    newD += `${lastX},${lastY}`; //M200,55L

    lastUC = c[0];
    newD += lastUC;

    //console.log(c)

    if (lastUC == "A") {
      newD += `${c[1]},${c[2]} ${c[3]} ${c[4]} ${Math.abs(c[5] - 1)}`;
    }

    if (lastUC == "C") {
      newD += `${c[3]},${c[4]} ${c[1]},${c[2]} `;
    }

    if (lastUC == "Q") {
      newD += `${c[1]},${c[2]} `;
    }
  }
  //remove the last M from the newD string
  if (newD.charAt(newD.length - 1) == "M") {
    newD = newD.substring(0, newD.length - 1);
  }

  if (closed) {
    newD += "Z";
  }

  return newD;
}

function S2C_T2Q(commands) {
  // a function to change S commands to C and T commands to Q

  let newCommands = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < commands.length; i++) {
    let command = commands[i];
    let previous = commands[i - 1];

    if (command[0] == "S") {
      newCommands.push(S2C(previous, command));
    } else if (command[0] == "T") {
      newCommands.push(T2Q(previous, command));
    } else {
      newCommands.push(command);
    }
  }
  return newCommands;
}
function ifClosedPath(commands) {
  // if the last command is "Z"
  if (commands[commands.length - 1][0] == "Z") {
    // remove the last item from array
    commands.pop();
    // copy the first command
    let lastCommand = commands[0].slice();
    // change the initial "M" with "L"
    lastCommand[0] = "L";
    // add the last command at the end of the commands array
    commands.push(lastCommand);
    // it's a closed array?: yes it is
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
//a function to change the T command to a Q command
function T2Q(previous, command) {
  let reflected = getReflectedPoint(previous, command);
  return ["Q", reflected.x, reflected.y, command[1], command[2]];
}
//a function to change the S command to a C command
function S2C(previous, command) {
  let reflected = getReflectedPoint(previous, command);
  return [
    "C",
    reflected.x,
    reflected.y,
    command[1],
    command[2],
    command[3],
    command[4]
  ];
}
// a function to get the reflected point for the T & S commands
function getReflectedPoint(previous, command) {
  let x2 = Number(previous[previous.length - 4]); //cp x
  let y2 = Number(previous[previous.length - 3]); //cp y
  let x3 = Number(previous[previous.length - 2]); //joining point x
  let y3 = Number(previous[previous.length - 1]); //joining point y

  ///////////////////////////////////////
  // the reflected control point
  let reflected = {};
  reflected.x = 2 * x3 - x2;
  reflected.y = 2 * y3 - y2;
  ///////////////////////////////////////

  return reflected;
}

//--------------Get the array of the svg commands---------
function formatedArgsArray(d) {
  //takes care of long commands
  /*The command letter can be eliminated on subsequent commands if the same command is used multiple times in a row (e.g., you can drop the second "L" in "M 100 200 L 200 100 L -100 -200" and use "M 100 200 L 200 100 -100 -200" instead).*/
  let ArgsRy = getArgsRys(d);
  let newArgsArray = [];
  ArgsRy.map((a, index) => {
    let prefix = a[0];
    let UCprefix = prefix.toUpperCase();

    let n, tempRy;
    if (UCprefix == "H" || UCprefix == "V") {
      n = 1;
    }
    if (UCprefix == "L" || UCprefix == "T" || UCprefix == "M") {
      n = 2;
    }
    if (UCprefix == "S" || UCprefix == "Q") {
      n = 4;
    }
    if (UCprefix == "C") {
      n = 6;
    }
    if (UCprefix == "A") {
      n = 7;
    }
    if (a.length > n + 1) {
      //if the length of the array a is longer than it should be
      tempRy = a.splice(1);
      //long_Absolute_command returns an array of arrays
      let newTempsArray = long_Absolute_command(tempRy, n, prefix);
      ArgsRy[index] = newTempsArray;
    }
  });

  ArgsRy.map(a => {
    if (Array.isArray(a[0])) {
      //if it's an array of arrays
      a.map(_a => {
        newArgsArray.push(_a);
      });
    } else {
      newArgsArray.push(a);
    }
  });

  return newArgsArray;
}

function long_Absolute_command(tempRy, n, prefix) {
  /* This function is splitting a long command like this:  ["L", 160", "160.622", "90", "160.622", "55", "100", "90", "39.378", "160", "39.378", "195", "100"] in several L commands: */
  //tempRy = ["160", "160.622", "90", "160.622", "55", "100", "90", "39.378", "160", "39.378", "195", "100"]
  //prefix = "L"
  //n = 2 (After the L comes 2 coords: x and y)

  let CommandsRy = [];

  while (tempRy.length > 0) {
    CommandsRy.push(tempRy.splice(0, n));
  }

  CommandsRy.forEach(c => {
    c = c.unshift(prefix);
  });

  // CommandsRy = [["L", "160", "160.622"],["L", "90", "160.622"],["L", "55", "100"],["L", "90", "39.378"],["L", "160", "39.378"],["L", "195", "100"]]

  return CommandsRy;
}

function getArgs(d) {
  //remove breaklines and tabs and spaces
  let _d = d.replace(/\r?\n|\r|\t|  +/g, "");

  if (_d.charAt(0) == "m") {
    _d = "M" + _d.slice(1);
  }
  let argsRX = /(?=[a-zA-Z])/;
  let args = _d.split(argsRX);

  return args;
}

function getArgsRys(d) {
  let args = getArgs(d);

  let ArgsRy = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    let values = args[i]
      .slice(1)
      .replace(/\-/g, " -")
      .split(/[ ,]+/);

    values.map((p, i) => {
      if (p == "") {
        values.splice(i, 1);
      }
    });

    let ry = [args[i].charAt(0)].concat(values);
    ArgsRy.push(ry);
  }
  return ArgsRy;
}
//--------------END Get the array of the svg commands-----

function SVG2UpperCase(commands) {
  for (let i = 1; i < commands.length; i++) {
    let c = commands[i];
    let prev = commands[i - 1];

    let x_ = Number(prev[prev.length - 2]);
    let y_ = Number(prev[prev.length - 1]);

    if (c[0].toUpperCase() !== c[0]) {
      //if is lower case

      switch (c[0]) {
        case "v":
          c[0] = "L";
          c[1] = x_; //x
          c[2] = Number(c[2]) + y_; //y
          break;
        case "h":
          c[0] = "L";
          c[1] = Number(c[1]) + x_; //x
          c[2] = y_; //y
          break;
        case "q":
        case "s":
          c[1] = Number(c[1]) + x_; //x
          c[2] = Number(c[2]) + y_; //y
          c[3] = Number(c[3]) + x_; //x
          c[4] = Number(c[4]) + y_; //y
          break;
        case "c":
          c[1] = Number(c[1]) + x_; //x
          c[2] = Number(c[2]) + y_; //y
          c[3] = Number(c[3]) + x_; //x
          c[4] = Number(c[4]) + y_; //y
          c[5] = Number(c[5]) + x_; //x
          c[6] = Number(c[6]) + y_; //y
          break;
        case "z":
          c[0] = "Z";
          break;
        default:
          // l, t, m, a
          c[c.length - 2] = Number(c[c.length - 2]) + x_; //x
          c[c.length - 1] = Number(c[c.length - 1]) + y_; //y
      }
    } // END if is lower case

    c[0] = c[0].toUpperCase();
  }

  return commands;
}
h4 {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

svg {
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  fill: none;
  stroke: green;
  stroke-width: 3px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 30rem;
  margin: 1em auto;
  display: block;
}

.wrap {
  max-width: 30rem;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

.wrap:nth-of-type(2) {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1em;
}
p {
  text-align: center;
}
em {
  font-family: serif;
}
#theDefs {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: -100em;
}
<h4>Reverse SVG path</h4> 
<p><em>Using a marker to show the change</em></p>
<div class="wrap"> 
<label>Input: the path you want to reverse</label>
<textarea id="TA">M10 80 Q 52.5 10, 95 80 T 180 80</textarea>
</div>


<div class="wrap">  
<svg id="theSVG">
    <path id="thePath" d="" marker-end="url(#arrow)"></path>
</svg>

<svg id="reversedSVG">
    <path id="reversedPath" d="" marker-end="url(#arrow)"></path>
</svg>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
<label>Output: the reversed path</label>
<textarea id="output"></textarea>
</div>  
</div>


<svg id="theDefs">
<defs>
<marker id="arrow" markerWidth="6" markerHeight="6" refX="3" refY="3" orient="auto" stroke="none" fill="green" >
<path d="M0,0L4,3L0,6Z" />
</marker>
</defs> 
</svg>




Мощно. Надо будет проверить работу с T, S - неужели так просто...

@Leonid к тому же есть возможность поменяв атрибуты увидеть как меняется форма кривой, тем самым лучше понять, как от цифр в атрибутах зависит форма кривой

Возможно автор вопроса взял профессиональную иконку, которые как правило, содержат несколько path и по умолчанию выполняются в черно-белом варианте, чтобы дать пользователю возможность использовать цвет, как есть, либо раскрасить разные участки иконки в разные цвета.
Совершенно не нужно было объединять несколько path в один.
Лишая себя гибкости при решении цветового соответствия иконки и своего веб приложения.
Ниже приведу несколько примеров получения многоцветных иконок с помощью переменных CSS


Черно-белый вариант иконки при наведении превращается в цветную иконку



:root {
  --sec:1s;
  }
 #armchair {
  --color-1: black;
  --color-2: black;
  --color-3: black;
 
 }

  #armchair:hover {
 --color-1: gold;
  --color-2: skyblue;
  --color-3: yellowgreen;
   
 }
 rect, path {
 transition: var(--sec);
{
<svg width="210" height="220" viewBox="0 0 21 22" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <g id="armchair">      
   
   <!-- Сопровождающий -->
    <path fill="var(--color-1)"   d="M7.3 18.4c0 .5-.3.8-.7.8a.8.8 0 0 1-.8-.8v-5.2l-.2-.2-.1.2v5.2c0 .5-.4.8-.8.8a.8.8 0 0 1-.8-.8V8l-.2-.1-.1.1v4c0 .4-.3.7-.7.7a.6.6 0 0 1-.6-.6V7.6c0-1 .8-1.7 1.8-1.7h3c1 0 1.8.7 1.8 1.7V12c0 .3-.3.6-.6.6a.6.6 0 0 1-.6-.6V8l-.2-.2-.2.1v10.5Zm-1.7-16c.8 0 1.5.7 1.5 1.5 0 .9-.7 1.5-1.5 1.5S4.1 4.8 4.1 4c0-.8.7-1.5 1.5-1.5Z"/>  

  <!--  Человек -->
  <path fill="var(--color-2)"  d="m18.6 17.7-1.7-3.4a.9.9 0 0 0-.8-.5H13v-3c0-.5-.4-1-.9-1s-.8.5-.8 1v3.9c0 .5.3.8.8.8h3.5l1.5 3c.1.3.4.5.7.5l.4-.1c.4-.2.6-.8.4-1.2Z" />
          <!--  коляска --> 
  <path fill="var(--color-3)"  d="M14.3 17c-.6.5-1.3.8-2 .8A3.2 3.2 0 0 1 9 14.6c0-1 .5-2 1.3-2.5.3-.3.4-.9.1-1.3a.8.8 0 0 0-1.2-.1 5 5 0 0 0-1.9 3.9 4.9 4.9 0 0 0 8.1 3.7c.4-.3.4-.8.1-1.2a.8.8 0 0 0-1.2 0ZM13.6 8c0 .7-.7 1.4-1.5 1.4s-1.4-.7-1.4-1.5.6-1.5 1.4-1.5c.8 0 1.5.7 1.5 1.5Z" />
     <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="transparent" />
  </g>
</svg>




При наведении меняется цветовая гамма иконки



:root {
  --sec:1s;
  }
 #armchair {
  --color-1: #c13127;
  --color-2: #FF00AE;
  --color-3: #cacaea;
 
 }

  #armchair:hover {
 --color-1: gold;
  --color-2: skyblue;
  --color-3: yellowgreen;
   
 }
 rect, path {
 transition: var(--sec);
{
<svg width="210" height="220" viewBox="0 0 21 22" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <g id="armchair">      
   
   <!-- Сопровождающий -->
    <path fill="var(--color-1)"   d="M7.3 18.4c0 .5-.3.8-.7.8a.8.8 0 0 1-.8-.8v-5.2l-.2-.2-.1.2v5.2c0 .5-.4.8-.8.8a.8.8 0 0 1-.8-.8V8l-.2-.1-.1.1v4c0 .4-.3.7-.7.7a.6.6 0 0 1-.6-.6V7.6c0-1 .8-1.7 1.8-1.7h3c1 0 1.8.7 1.8 1.7V12c0 .3-.3.6-.6.6a.6.6 0 0 1-.6-.6V8l-.2-.2-.2.1v10.5Zm-1.7-16c.8 0 1.5.7 1.5 1.5 0 .9-.7 1.5-1.5 1.5S4.1 4.8 4.1 4c0-.8.7-1.5 1.5-1.5Z"/>  

  <!--  Человек -->
  <path fill="var(--color-2)"  d="m18.6 17.7-1.7-3.4a.9.9 0 0 0-.8-.5H13v-3c0-.5-.4-1-.9-1s-.8.5-.8 1v3.9c0 .5.3.8.8.8h3.5l1.5 3c.1.3.4.5.7.5l.4-.1c.4-.2.6-.8.4-1.2Z" />
          <!--  коляска --> 
  <path fill="var(--color-3)"  d="M14.3 17c-.6.5-1.3.8-2 .8A3.2 3.2 0 0 1 9 14.6c0-1 .5-2 1.3-2.5.3-.3.4-.9.1-1.3a.8.8 0 0 0-1.2-.1 5 5 0 0 0-1.9 3.9 4.9 4.9 0 0 0 8.1 3.7c.4-.3.4-.8.1-1.2a.8.8 0 0 0-1.2 0ZM13.6 8c0 .7-.7 1.4-1.5 1.4s-1.4-.7-1.4-1.5.6-1.5 1.4-1.5c.8 0 1.5.7 1.5 1.5Z" />
     <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="transparent" />
  </g>
</svg>




Голова деформировалась почему-то... Классный ответ! Мне бы галку убрать, не для того отвечал и не ответ на галку. Пусть без нее вообще тогда если технически на ответ испанского гуру не поставить.
